# Gas pipe from meter starts at 1" then expands to 1.25"

Tags: gas

The first line coming from the T on my gas meter is 1" but the line after the elbow, going into the house, is 1.25".  I'm going to be adding a gas range and need the capacity of the 1.25" pipe to supply all my appliances including the range.  Is that first length of 1" pipe going to restrict the flow and capacity of the 1.25" pipe?

[image: pipe from gas meter]

Comment: Not enough information here.  What’s the size of the gas service? What’s the T splitting?  It’s possibly the House was plumbed at 1.25” but the gas service installed is only 1”.

Comment: But probably you are OK. I would just install the new equipment and see if it works, and other gas fired equipment works when the range is being used.

Comment: @JimStewart except that 1/4” pretty much doubles capacity http://www.endot.com/OpenFile.aspx?path=21eb7_0.pdf&Type=1&pid=34 and the drawback is the day it’s discovered that it’s undersized due to performance it will probably be -10 outside.

Comment: Yes, but if the length of 1" pipe is short compared to the length of 1.25" then the effect is very small. The gas supply tables show how to calculate this. I think you are right to wonder about the meter itself. It would be reasonable to contact the gas company and tell them that a new gas range is being installed and ask about upgrading.

Comment: The gas company states the capacity of the meter is 350K BTU.  I believe the incoming pipe is 3/4".  Outlet PSI is .25.  The "T" I was referring to is the one with the plug, so it isn't actually splitting anything.  I'm planning to add a T to send a dedicated 1" line to a new 163K BTU range 40' away.....so I'm mostly wondering if I should add the T at the end of that vertical 1" line in the picture or if it would be worth replacing that vertical run with 1 1/4".